# Select a div ending with some things

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div id="start_123_end"</div>
<div id = "start_123_ok"</div>
<div id="start_123_error"</div>
<div id = "start_123_notstarted"</div>
```

I want to select a div which start with "start" and ends with "end " or "ok"

```
Pseduo Code:
```

vae selected $("div[id^=__w2][id$=_end || _ok]")

as there can be many elements

Comment: @UweB - you can't do `||` in jQuery.

Comment: well i will suggest to use Data tag , see the link for the info http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
var selected = $("div[id^=start]").filter("[id$=_ok],[id$=_end]");
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/NJPLL/)

Comment: @SomPathak, Yes you can use it similarly

Comment: one more if i want to use length attribute also $("div[id^=start]").filter("[id$=_ok],[id$=_end]").length<10 length here is length of class name

Comment: well i will suggest to use Data tag http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp

Answer (score 2):

Use start and end selector with comma

```
$('div[id ^=start][id $=_ok],div[id ^=start][id $=_end ]')
```

Comment: one more if i want to use length attribute also $("div[id^=start]").filter("[id$=_ok],[id$=_end]").length<10 length here is length of class name

Comment: @SomPathak ya You can use $('div[id ^=start][id $=_ok],div[id ^=start][id $=_end ]').length

Answer (score 0):

Instead of rather slow attribute selectors, you can use a `filter` with a regex:

```
$('div').filter(function() {
   return /^start.+(end|ok)$/.test(this.id);
}).addClass('selected');
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/W8SZJ/)